# How to create expression tree statement for the unchecked-statement

Tags: c#, code-generation

In my expression tree (created with the `Expression` class) I need to wrap my code in an unchecked block (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx) but how? There is nothing interesting on the `Expression` type.

Comment: A quick test in LINQPad I think shows that if you have an `Expression.NodeType` of `Add` it's unchecked, and `AddChecked` is with checking. This matches with the information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361179%28v=vs.110%29.aspx which distinguishes the two and is documented as such. (there are similar "checked" ones for other arithmetic operations)

Comment: Hmm, maybe this is in concert with the [`/checked` compiler flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h25wtyxf.aspx) or if you've constructed your expression within a `checked` block? If so, then when you write `Expression expr => () => something + 10;`, it will _automatically_ use the `AddChecked` expression type, but with those flags off (or not in a `checked` block) the same line will produce it with an `Add` node type. Could you maybe provide us more information about _how_ you're producing your expression trees?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Expression` type has separate versions of each operator for checked and unchecked operations.  To change any `checked` operations within the expression's body to `unchecked` operations you can't just wrap the whole thing in an `unchecked` expression.  You'd need to traverse the entire expression tree, find all uses of checked operations and replace them with the unchecked versions of those operations.

```
public static Expression MakeUnchecked(this Expression expression)
{
    return new UncheckedExpressionVisitor().Visit(expression);
}

public class UncheckedExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
    {
        switch (node.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.AddAssignChecked:
                return base.Visit(Expression.AddAssign(node.Left, node.Right));
            case ExpressionType.AddChecked:
                return base.Visit(Expression.Add(node.Left, node.Right));
            case ExpressionType.MultiplyAssignChecked:
                return base.Visit(Expression.MultiplyAssign(node.Left, node.Right));
            case ExpressionType.MultiplyChecked:
                return base.Visit(Expression.Multiply(node.Left, node.Right));
            case ExpressionType.SubtractAssignChecked:
                return base.Visit(Expression.SubtractAssign(node.Left, node.Right));
            case ExpressionType.SubtractChecked:
                return base.Visit(Expression.Subtract(node.Left, node.Right));
            default:
                return base.VisitBinary(node);
        }
    }

    protected override Expression VisitUnary(UnaryExpression node)
    {
        switch (node.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.ConvertChecked:
                return base.Visit(Expression.Convert(node.Operand, node.Type));
            case ExpressionType.NegateChecked:
                return base.Visit(Expression.Negate(node.Operand, node.Method));
            default:
                return base.VisitUnary(node);
        }
    }
}
```